# Redis finding hashes by field values

Tags: nosql, redis

When using Redis in order to create a "record" you can create a hash with several fields. For example:

```
HMSET myhash field1 "Hello" field2 "World"
HMSET myhash2 field1 "Goodbye" field2 "World"
```

You can retrieve this by knowing the key values, however what I want to know is there any way to retrieve all hashes that have "World" in field2?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are no indexes in redis, and it doesn't implement SQL. It's a key-value store. You provide a key, it gets you a value.

That said, you can implement this by maintaining secondary indexes yourself. For example:

create a record and an index entry

```
HMSET myhash field1 Hello field2 World
SADD field2_world myhash
```

update a record, delete old index entry, create new one

```
SREM field2_world myhash
HMSET myhash field2 Mundo
SADD field2_mundo myhash
```

find all records which have "World" in `field2`

```
SMEMBERS field2_world
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: i executed the exact commands in the answer with 2 hashes and it did not work. may you explain a bit more?

Comment: @SHM: How it didn't work? Show your entire command history for that session. With outputs.

Answer (score -2):

For next readers, the [SORT command](https://redis.io/commands/sort) would probably help using the "BY pattern" argument

```
HMSET myhash field1 Hello field2 World
SORT myhash BY World
```

[Patterns examples (w3resource)](https://www.w3resource.com/redis/redis-key-pattern.php)

Comment: Doesn't work on Redis 7.0.0, failing with error `(error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value`

Comment: Also this is sorting a specific key. The original question was how to get that specific key, that you are assuming one already knows.