# RedisTemplate get hash key by value

Tags: spring, redis

I'm very new both on Spring and Redis. I would like to know if there is a way to get the KEY by value?

> My KEY is patterned like this: "{**typeOfFile**}:{**id**}:{**filename**}"
>
> **typeOfFile** could either be *"image"*, *"html"*, or *"pdf"*.

For instance, I want to get the get the KEY of an *image* type of file with a given *fileHash* and *content*. I'm doing it with this kind of idea:

```
private String getKeyByVal(final String givenFileHash, final String content) {
    // get all keys that starts with "image"
    Set<String> keys = redisTemplate.keys("image*");
    if (keys != null) {
        for (String key : keys) {
            Map<Object, Object> val = redisTemplate.opsForHash().entries(key);
            // check if the value of KEY is equal to the given fileHash
            if (val.get("fileHash").equals(givenFileHash) && val.get("content").equals(content)) {
               return key;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I was told that this is quite costly since I'm getting all the keys that starts with "image", and manually check all of them.

Now I'm thinking, maybe it would be much better if I can get the KEY by value. So that it would be easier to get all of its properties. Is that possible in Redis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis finding hashes by field values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209613/redis-finding-hashes-by-field-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Redis. You can however store a reverse map in simultaneous as below:

```
    fileHash -> "{typeOfFile}:{id}:{filename}"
```

This solution assumes that the file hash is unique. If the hash is not unique then you can store a set of ids with the same hash, retrieve the content for each of them and compare. Still a lot faster than the original solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I will try to apply your suggestion.