# redis - how to find an entry in hmset using just the value?

Tags: redis

I need to manage a 'set' of data about the availability of accounts.  So far, I am creating a SET like this:

```
 127.0.0.1:6379[2]> hmset accounts 73075 available
 OK
 127.0.0.1:6379[2]> hmset accounts 73076 reserved
 OK

127.0.0.1:6379[2]> hget accounts 73075 
"available"
127.0.0.1:6379[2]>
```

**Questions**

1. How can I query to find all accounts that are "available"? I've been trying to find some examples on line, but I've come up empty.  I might be using the wrong key words to search on google.  I'm going to continue to try.
2. Later I need to extend this so that I'm not just saying an account is "reserved" but I will need associate it with a name.  Wondering if the SET is the right way to do this.

**EDIT 1**

I just found this [Redis finding hashes by field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209613/redis-finding-hashes-by-field-values)

Will try to create another index for myself.  But is this a good approach?  If you smell something funny in my code / concept please let me know.

**EDIT 2**

So far, this is what I have based on the article above:

```
 127.0.0.1:6379[2]> sadd johndoe@yahoo.com 73075
 (integer) 1
 127.0.0.1:6379[2]> smembers johndoe@yahoo.com
 1) "73075"
```

I guess this can solve question 2 where later on down the road I can find all John Doe's accounts. 
But I still can't figure out how to find all "available" accounts. 
I could create an index as well, for each available account.  But is there a better way?

**EDIT 3**

Perhaps this is a better approach?
Create a SET called "available" and populate it with all the accounts.

```
 HMSET available 12345 dontneedthisfield
```

Then when an account is reserved, add to another SET called reserved:

```
 HMSET reserved 12345 johndoe
 HDEL available 12345
```

Is this a better approach?

Comment: Yep - another data structure to index the "available" accounts is exactly what you'd need.

Comment: @ItamarHaber can you see EDIT 3 in my  post?  what do you think?

Comment: Use a real Set (i.e. `SADD`) instead of a Hash because you really dont' need that field.